# A comma followed by "and" rule

Tags: structure

I'm not a native english speaker. I have been taught in school that if you use a comma, you should not use `and` after it.

I went to university, my university teacher said the same and if he said that if i don't follow that rule, I'll fail my Toefl exam.

I was reading the FAQ of this website and i saw this

`Writers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for authors, editors, reviewers, professional writers, and aspiring writers.`

According to my teachers, it's a mistake, the sentence should be like this

`... professional writers and aspiring writers.`

But you guys know more than me since you are native speakers, so what why was i taught this rule in the first place and why does the Toefl mention it?

Comment: Grammar is off-topic here as per [our FAQ](http://writers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), but have sent this to English Language Learners.